# Copying an array to a list

Tags: java

I am wondering if there's a one-line way of copying an array to a list than the following:

```
String array[] = new String[]{"1", "2", "3", "4" } ;

List list = new ArrayList();

for (int i=0; i< array.length; i++){
    list.add(array[i] );
}
```

Edit: thanks for both informative answers, very helpful :)

Comment: Please use the generic version of `List`. Also, `List<E>` is an interface, so it cannot be instantiated: you may create an `ArrayList<E>` or a `LinkedList<E>` instead.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I had to start with but I changed it to list before I posted the question here by mistake.

Comment: You still have to add the type parameter, e.g. `List<String>`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes there is a one liner, use [**Arrays.asList(T...a)**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) to convert an array into list and pass it as an argument into the ArrayList overloaded constructor which takes a Collection.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(array))
```

Comment: `List<E>` is an interface, so you cannot instantiate it. Maybe you meant `new ArrayList<String>()`?

Comment: @GiulioPiancastelli oops. sorted that :)

Comment: The new is useful only if you want to modify the list, else the answer of Cratylus is better

Answer (score 6):

If you need the array in list format but do not actually need to modify structurally the array you can do: `List<String> list = Arrays.asList(array);`.
Otherwise the answer of@PremGenError is the one to go for.

Comment: +1 for the explanation of the difference between `Arrays.asList()` and the creation of a new list altogether.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest approach is:

```
List<String> fixedList = Arrays.asList(array);
```

However this will return a fixed-size list backed by the specified array.
This means that an attempt to modify the list (such as `list.add("10")`) 
will result in a `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException`**at run-time** - so be careful.

A modifiable list can be constructed based on the fixed-size list:

```
List<String> modifiableList = new ArrayList<String>(fixedList);
```

Both steps can be amalgamated into a single line of code, like so:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(array));
```